# HTML footer {position: absolute, fixed;} overlaps with site content, {position: relative, sticky;} floats to the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been scouring a few dozen different pages to try to find a solution that applies to the situation I have.

I am creating a portfolio website with my projects, but the footer is behaving abnormally to resizing.

When I use

```
footer{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -100;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }
```

This is the result I get at **100%** zoom:
[1920x1080 * 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsW0B.png) (Perfect)

This is the result I get at **125%** zoom:
[1920x1080 * 125%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSs3V.png) (Overlap between `<body><div><p>` & `<footer>`)

As you can see, my `<p>` contents begin to overlap with the footer element.

When I use the sticky positioning, `footer{ position: sticky;}`, the footer floats up and attaches itself to the bottom of `{p}` [As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pIWf.png). I thought of two solutions but neither worked, ideally I would like the `<body>` to encompass **at least** (the entire screen - the size of the footer) (and whatever other elements that are not in the body) and have the footer as sticky. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally to fix it you need to set width and heigth with the size vw and vh.

vw -> It's width the screen.
vh -> It's height of the screen.

In your tag `<body>` set `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`.

Note: Another thing "`position: absolute`" uses its parent to reposition itself

Comment: Is there a way for me to use a function as input for height/width? Something like`height: (100vh - 200px)` or `(100vh - $footer.height)`

What you said works but it effectively hides my navbar until the user scrolls down and finds it

Comment: Yes, you can use `width: calc(100vh - 200px)`

Comment: Last question, is there a way for me to access the width for a named variable? suppose my `<div id="footer" style="height: 100px;">` Am I able to access `#footer.height?`

Comment: You can use just javascript to do it -> document.querySelector('element').clientWidth